# Elasticsearch reindexing with no replica

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I have a cluster of four nodes with no replicas because I don't care losing data at all. 
When I lose one of the nodes, will the rest nodes reindex the data? Is there anything going to happen apart from losing 25% of the data?